# Do sortable tables support sorting within multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010 (and perhaps recent versions), you can select a range of data and insert a table over it that adds user-friendly sorting capabilities to the data.  However, it appears that it doesn't support sorting across multiple columns.  For example, I might want to sort column A then sort columb B within column A.

Is there a way to achieve this using native functionality that doesn't involve having to write a macro?  I am also excluding the use of Excel's sort option from the toolbar/ribbon since this is a more advanced feature than not many novice Excel users (business owners, other higher-ups, etc) know how to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no native way to achieve this.

Your best bet is to write (or get someone else to write) an add-in that creates a new button bar with a series of switches to turn on/off sorting for each column. Shouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: Good answer, but makes me unhappy.

Comment: Sorry! Don't shoot the messenger though!

Answer (score 2):

Since filtering supports multiple columns, but it is not what you are looking for, here is how to add sorting to multiple columns without using the toolbar/ribbon. Right click in a cell on the sheet and point to `sort` in the context menu. Then choose `Custom Sort` in the sub menu.

This brings up the `Sort` window. You can add the sort criteria here and add levels of sorting.

[image]

Although this is pretty straight forward and easy, I don't think you will be able to completely avoid having to explain to the end user how to do some things. A little bit of training goes a long way.

Comment: Filtering or sorting?  I don't want to filter anything out.

Comment: Yep. You are right, filtering does exclude data. I was trying to give you an option since you excluded use of the toolbar/ribbon. Let me re-answer then.

Comment: I already excluded that option in my question, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by selecting Sort under the Data tab in the ribbon.

Comment: I knew I should have also excluded this as an option.  I am looking for a more user-friendly alternative that leaves all the options obvious to the user.  Too many business owners and higher-ups have no idea where to find most options in Office applications, let alone know they exist.

Comment: I suggest you update your original question then